# can't import ethjsonrpc in python3.6 , ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, encode, ethereum

when importing `ethjsonrpc` It throws an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ethjsonrpc.client import (EthJsonRpc, ParityEthJsonRpc,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/client.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ethereum import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethereum/utils.py", line 103, in <module>
    assert sha3('').encode('hex') == 'c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470'
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with `ethjsonrpc` as can be seen on the [github issue page](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc/issues/41). The proposed fix is to just comment the line 103 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethereum/utils.py`

Might be a good idea to switch to using this module with python2 instead in case more errors appear that are caused by version differences.